# Unable to clean gradle project

Tags: gradle

I am starting out with Gradle. I have written my build script, but now Gradle claims always it is UP-TO-DATE, but I manually deleted the output folder, so it is no longer up to date. I tried with '`--rerun-tasks`', '`clean`' or '`cleanSomeTask`' but it keeps saying UP-TO-DATE.

I also tried removing the `.gradle` directory that gets created in the project folder, but still the same. Is there anything else I can try?

My build file has a custom name, so I always specify the '`-b`' option to point to that file, I don't know if that is important or not.

This is my build file (`modbus-script.gradle`):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

defaultTasks 'packageAll'

apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'java'

def buildFolderName = 'target/modbus'
def buildFolder = new File( buildFolderName )
def buildFolderZipSource = "${buildFolderName}/zip-source"
def scriptSrcLocation = 'src/main/script/com/company/script/groovy/modbus'
def scriptSrcName = 'Modbus.groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.wimpi', name: 'jamod', version: '1.2.3'
    compile group: 'org.rxtx', name:'rxtx', version: '2.1.7'
}

def buildTime() {
    def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm")
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    return df.format(new Date())
}

task prepare {
    println "Preparing..."
    buildFolder.mkdirs()

}

task copyGroovyScript(dependsOn: prepare, type: Copy) << {
    from "${scriptSrcLocation}/${scriptSrcName}"
    into buildFolderZipSource
}

task copyDependencies(dependsOn: copyGroovyScript, type: Copy) << {
     from sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
     into "${buildFolderZipSource}/groovy-plugin-lib"
}

task packageAll(dependsOn: copyDependencies, type:Zip) << {
    archiveName "modbus-${buildTime()}.zip"
    destinationDir buildFolder
    from buildFolder
}
```

Comment: The question comes with too little details as well it difficult to reproduce it.

Comment: Added gradle build script

Comment: In task `prepare` there's no action added `<<` - `buildFolder` will be created every time gradle runs. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different tasks are marked as up-to-date because gradle things there is nothing to copy. Running the build with `-i` will provide you further information why a task is marked as up-to-date.

The problem why those tasks are marked as up-to-date is that you use `<<` when declaring your tasks. This means you're adding a task action instead of configuring your task. Get rid of the `<<`'s in your build script and try again.

Comment: Removing the `<<` makes it work indeed. Can you explain the exact difference between using `<<` and not using it? The basic examples on https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html all seem to be using it, so that is why I also used it.

Comment: have a look at the Example 56.1 of the gradle userguide at https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html to understand the difference between task configuration and adding task actions. In short `<<{}`is just a shortcut for `doLast {}`